# making a line run once, Text based game

Tags: c++, text

I am doing a text based game in class for  beginner coders, and I need some quick help.

case 1:

```
        cout << "\n You are in a underground room you, look around there is no way back up to the  hole you fell through. \n";
        cin >> input;



    if ( input == 'l'){
        cout << "\n You turn left and see a dull lanturn.\n";
            cin>>input;
                if ( input == 'g')
                    cout << "\n You grab the dull lanturn\n";
                        cin>>input;
                            if ( input == 'u')
    cout << "\n You turn the lanturn on, it casts a bright light. \n";      
        }

         if ( input == 'r')
            cout << "\n You turn right, and see nothing of interest.\n";

        else if (input == 'n')
            room = 2;

        else
            cout<<"input not recognized"<<endl;
        break;
```

I only want this line to run one time

```
                 if ( input == 'l'){
        cout << "\n You turn left and see a dull lanturn.\n";
            cin>>input;
                if ( input == 'g')
                    cout << "\n You grab the dull lanturn\n";
                        cin>>input;
                            if ( input == 'u')
    cout << "\n You turn the lanturn on, it casts a bright light. \n";      
        }
```

How do I go about doing this.

Comment: Lantern, not lanturn.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing from your `break` statement, and the strings, you are in a loop that keeps asking for input and then does something depending on the input.

Knowing this, you should begin by figuring out *when* you want this line to run and develop a strategy from there.

E.g. if you decide that the first time someone presses `'l'` you wish to execute the `if` statement, than you need to keep a reminder of whether you already went through there and test that in your condition.

If you decide that it can only happen when you are in a certain room and do not have a (lit?) lantern in your inventory, then your check becomes more complicated, because it needs to test more conditions, but still works along the same basic principle.

Finally, you may be missing an `else` before the `if(input == 'r')`, leading to the possibility that the user types `"lr"`, which would execute two `if`s in one iteration of your loop.